# Activating PHP extensions in Bluemix

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ibm-cloud, php-extension

This is a purely Bluemix question!

I've got code running smoothly on a localhost but when I migrated it to Bluemix my DB connection failed me. Checking the logs I found the issue "Call to undefined function mysqli_init()" HTTP response 500. I have found out that extension have been disabled to make it smaller and have found some details about it: [Buildpack options](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md?cm_mc_uid=33782485281614374684850&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1440413165).

Unfortunately I have tried that and failed. Maybe I have misunderstood the solution.

[image: Screenshot]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

bgconfig --> bp-config solved the "undefined function error"

It seems that some extension have been added but not all. "Fatal error:Class 'PDO' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/db_config.php on line 15"

I have however added the PDO extension in options.json.

I tried adding a php.ini overwrite [image: Screenshot]

But still get the same error...

For info: line 15 on db_config.php is simply:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net;dbname=ad_dae231843a962ca', $username, $password);}
```

within try & catch of course.

Any Clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `options.json` file is correct that you have posted.  However it is in the wrong directory, it should be in a folder called `.bp-config/`.  Renamed the folder and repush your app back to Bluemix.

Also try adding `pdo_mysql` to `.bp-config/options.json`.

I just tested some code with the PDO driver against a DB and it worked fine.  My `.bp-config/options.json` file is below.

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["pdo", "mysqli", "pdo_mysql", "mysql"]
}
```

I would double check your access to the database with a MySQL desktop client.  It looks like an issue with your connection information.

I have an [example app](https://github.com/jsloyer/testphp) for testing your connection information with PDO.

Comment: Solved my "undefined function issue: but now I get this in my logs.
[link](http://s2.postimg.org/718mjv03t/Capture.png)

Any clue why it gives me so many errors?

Comment: @FrenchMassacre can you update your question with the error you are getting?

Comment: @FrenchMassacre try adding `pdo_mysql` to `.bp-config/options.json`

Comment: added that, no change :(

Comment: Can you try adding a little more debugging and logging to your app to catch errors to try to figure whats going on?

Comment: @FrenchMassacre also did you add `pdo_mysql` to `.bp-config/options.json`?  The screenshot you have above doesnt include it.

Comment: updated the screenshot, what kind of debugging/logging would you like me to add? I've added a few in the php.ini file but they haven't been very helpful (I also get no errors in my log since the first issue was fixed.)

Comment: @FrenchMassacre You dont need the `php/php.ini` file.  Please delete that.

Comment: @FrenchMassacre can you put up a page with `phpinfo()` in it?

Comment: @FrenchMassacre looks like an issue with your db connection information, please double check your connection information with a desktop client.

Comment: Don't know why but it suddenly started to work... no changes since yesterday.... Thanks Jeff. Great help!

Comment: Needed one simple example which you provided in the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions to add the options.json file are the correct ones and from your screenshot the file looks to be correct. The problem is the directory that you placed the options.json file in you have called `.bgconfig` when it should be `.bp-config`.

Can you change the directory name, repush the app to Bluemix and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have mysql defined in your `composer.json`?

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/php-mysql

Answer (score -1):

**you can add extension in composer.json file**

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mysqli": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*"
  }
}
```