# Access to ClearDB on Bluemix with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo, connection, ibm-cloud, cleardb

I'm trying to create a Bluemix Application using **PHP** and **ClearDB** (using **PDO** to connect).

When I try to access the server using my localhost (WAMP) I can get the connection successful message. When I simply copy and past the code on Bluemix, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/includes/db.php on line 43
```

I'm sure that my credentials works because I used the same credentials to connect via MySQL Workbench.
I'm sure that my syntax is correct because I can connect using localhost (WAMP).

I searched and found that I need to activate the PDO as PHP Extensions (I already see this post [Activating PHP extensions in Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180674/activating-php-extensions-in-bluemix) but no success).

Some configuration files:

.bp-config -> php -> php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = On
```

.bp-config -> options.json

```
{ 
   "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["bz2", "zlib", "openssl", "fpm", "tokenizer", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "PDO", "pdo_mysql", "mysql", "mysqli"]
 }
```

line 43 from /home/vcap/app/htdocs/includes/db.php

```
 $this->conn = new PDO($strcon, $this->user, $this->password)
```

[Server Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgKd8.jpg)

Someone can help me to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: did you look at the server's error log to see what the 500 is about? fiddling about with config files is pointless until you've found out what the error REALLY is.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180674/activating-php-extensions-in-bluemix

Comment: Hello @JeffSloyer, I already tried the solutions gave on that post, but I couldn't fix....

Comment: Hello @MarcB, I'm not getting error 500 anymore, but the PDO still not working

Comment: you're got .so and .dll files being loaded. .so is for unix systems, .dll is for windows. you CAN'T mix them. if you checked your php/apache error logs, you'd probably see a bunch of errors/warnings about being unable to load the dlls (since your system path suggests you're on a unixish system).

Comment: Can you please post some more information?  Its hard to debug this without logs... Run cf logs appname --recent

Comment: @MarcB thanks, I removed the .dll files but the same error

Comment: well, yeah. you don't have the pdo library loaded, and removing the dlls won't help, because they couldn't be loaded in the first place. you need to load up the pdo drivers for your specific host OS.

Comment: @JeffSloyer I edited the post with an image of the logs I get, it seams that it couldn't load the extensions....

Comment: @LeandroSerain you dont need the php.ini file.

Comment: @MarcB yes I couldn't load it, I added the server log. As I'm using bluemix I'm not sure the server details

Comment: @JeffSloyer I removed the php.ini file and now the application just stop when reach the pdo line, no errors, it just stop

Comment: Can you post some of the logs?

Comment: @LeandroSerain can you post some of the logs?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me @JeffSloyer, I could make it work, I'll post the solution as an answer of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it (with the help of @Jeff and @ Marc), here is the solution:

The only thing I needed was:

.bp-config>options.json

```
{
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["bz2", "zlib", "openssl", "fpm", "tokenizer", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "pdo", "pdo_mysql", "mysql", "mysqli"]
}
```